# QML how to set the font size of a list header to a consistent value

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to set the `header` of a `ListView` to a consistent `font` sizes. Given that I also need it to automatically grow based on the `height` and `width` of the container, how can I achieve a good looking `header` row?
What I tried already is the below. One way of solving this is not to set the width of each `Text` the same way and give different `preferredWidth` to each based on the string length. BUT, what if my string is dynamically loaded and I don't know how long my string would be. What is a good way of achieving a good looking header instead of the one I have. Thanks.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 200

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text {
            text: qsTr("Short")
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 1
            fontSizeMode: Text.HorizontalFit | Text.VerticalFit
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            minimumPointSize: 12
            font.pointSize: 40

        }
        Text {
            text: qsTr("Medium String")
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 1
            fontSizeMode: Text.HorizontalFit | Text.VerticalFit
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            minimumPointSize: 12
            font.pointSize: 40
        }
        Text {
            text: qsTr("A much longer String")
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 1
            fontSizeMode: Text.HorizontalFit | Text.VerticalFit
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            minimumPointSize: 12
            font.pointSize: 40
        }
        Text {
            text: qsTr("An absurdly and unecessary long String!!")
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 1
            fontSizeMode: Text.HorizontalFit | Text.VerticalFit
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            minimumPointSize: 12
            font.pointSize: 40
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I got it!!! using this helped A LOT `Layout.preferredWidth: text.length` any thoughts?

Comment: one thing to keep in mind, the `header` in this case might/will not match the other columns of the `ListView` since there could be different lengths of data inside :/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You are talking about `ListView` and `header` but there is no `ListView` in your code example. Where is the binding on `font` size that you are talking about? Please post what you've tried with your `ListView`, and the actual code that correspond to your screenshot.